# how to transform rdf file to hive table

Tags: mapreduce, hive, rdf, owl, ontology

I have to transform an RDF file into a hive or hbase table and apply a MapReduce job to it.  I know how to manipulate hive, but I don't know how to put triples into rows and columns.  The following RDF file (from DBpedia) contains multiple triples.

```xml
<rdf:RDF
        xmlns = "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
        xml:base="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
        xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">

    <!-- Ontology Information -->
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
      <owl:versionInfo xml:lang="de">Version 3.2 2008-11-17</owl:versionInfo>
    </owl:Ontology>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace">
      <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Populated Place</rdfs:label>
      <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Place</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Country</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Area">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Area</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Municipality">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Municipality</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">City</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/River">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">River</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/HistoricPlace">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Historic Place</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place"/>
    </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: (I'm speaking as someone who hasn't used hive.)  RDF is a graph based data representation, and the fundamental piece of data is the labeled directed edge, called a triple, typically presented as [subject, predicate, object].  The simplest table structure you could produce from that would be a table with three columns: subject, predicate, and object.  That said, the data that you're showing is a small OWL ontology with nothing but class declarations with a little bit of class hierarchy structure.  You might be able to store that in a table with more columns, but the transformation will be more

Comment: complex, of course.  If you can tell us what columns you'd like to have, or how the data is supposed to be structured, as well as showing your attempts so far, you'll be much more likely to get some useful responses.  As it stands now, this is probably too broad, and doesn't provide enough information to construct a useful answer.